# Dynamically created dojo components don't get CSS style applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a html file where I instance a new Javascript object. It that code I dynamically create some dojo components. I have the CSS style included in the HTML file. But the components doen't get the correct look. Am I missing something?

Here is some of my code: 
Creation of a component:

```
 var buttonToolbar = new dijit.Toolbar({});     
    buttonToolbar.addChild(
        new dijit.form.Button({
            label: "1x1 layout",
            onClick: function() { mv.createLayout(1, 1);},
            iconClass: "myIcon1",
            class: "dhButton"
        })
    );
```

HTML head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-demo.css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/vendor/dh/medview/css/medview.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/widget/Dialog/Dialog.css" /> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");     
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                   dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
                    //new object creation
                        }
                    );
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: No errors in console or IDE!

Comment: have you added the "claro" class to your body?

Comment: How do you mean add to the body? I've included the CSS in the head section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add class `claro` to the body tag like this.

```
<body class="claro">
```

Guide : https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/themes.html

And check again that you have set `parseOnLoad` in [`dojoConfig`](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dojo_config/) like this.

```
dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true
};
```

**Note :** If you use `parseOnLoad: true` you should not use `parser.parse()` [See more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14515888/1115817)